# How to read an integer that starts with zero?

Tags: java

This is a program to read an integer:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

But if I enter an input like this: `000114` it will be read like `114`.How to read integer starts with zeroes?

Comment: there is not integer with zero before the number it must be String, but you can convert it to integer

Comment: Read it as a string, eg with `input.next()` or `input.nextLine()` and then you can convert it to an int with `Integer.parse()`

Comment: Why do you need the leading zeroes? Perhaps the raw `String` is what you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting String to Int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/converting-string-to-int-in-java)

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ What the OP wants is to preserve the leading 0's, not only convert a `String` to an `int`. I believe this is not a dupe of the question you have linked.

Comment: Do you mean you want to read 0114 as an octal number, not a decimal?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥıλɐɯ I don't think it's a duplicate since OP is not asking how to convert an String to int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Zeros are ignored at the start of an `int`. If you need the zeros to be displayed, store the number as a `String` instead. If you need to use it for calculations later, you can convert it to an `int` using `Integer.parseInt()`, so your code should look like this:

```
String x = input.next();
System.out.println(x);

//if you need x to be an int
int xInt = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

Keep in mind that, in this example, `xInt` will lose the zeros.

Comment: That was the best solution for my question. other solutions are also very useful and good solutions. thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should read the input as a string and not as an integer if you really need to have the leading zeroes.

Answer (score 3):

That is the expected outcome when reading an int with leading 0s because 000114 isn't an int when represented like that.
If you need it to be 000114 then you should read it as a string.